# Javascript Show/Hide not working in IE8

Tags: javascript, show-hide

I have this bit of code that is working in FF, Chrome, Safari, and even IE9. Naturally, it doesn't work in IE8. It's a show/hide on two divs using Javascript. I'm not terribly proficient with JS so any help would be appreciated.

**Javascript function :**

```
function showonlyone(thechosenone) {
  var subscriberinfo = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
  for(var x=0; x<subscriberinfo.length; x++) {
    name = subscriberinfo[x].getAttribute("class");
    if (name == 'subscriberinfo') {
      if (subscriberinfo[x].id == thechosenone) {
        subscriberinfo[x].style.display = 'block';
      } else {
        subscriberinfo[x].style.display = 'none';
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**HTML code :**

```
<ul class="options">
  <div class="subscriber-options">
    <a href="javascript:showonlyone('subscriberinfo1');" >Account</a>
  </div>
  <div class="subscriber-options">
    <a href="javascript:showonlyone('subscriberinfo2');" >Subscriber Options</a>
  </div>
</ul>
<!-- options -->
<div class="subscriberinfo" id="subscriberinfo1">Div #1</div>
<!-- subscriberinfo1 -->
<div class="subscriberinfo" id="subscriberinfo2" style="display: none;">Div #2</div>
```

Comment: "XYZ feature not working in IE8" - what else do you expect?

Comment: According to [a forum post](http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/javascript-dhtml-ajax/threads/324560/how-to-hide-and-unhide-div-tag-in-ie7-and-ie8) you might be able to use CSS classes to accomplish this.

Comment: Using `javascript:` schemed links is not recommended practice.

Comment: @Rocketpig Can you check if IE8 is in quirks mode when it doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry, I should have elaborated. I was running IE9 in Compatibility Mode. I don't have a native copy of IE8 on this machine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of `getAttribute("class")` have you tried `className`?

```
function showonlyone(thechosenone) {
  var subscriberinfo = document.getElementsByTagName("div");

  for(var x=0; x<subscriberinfo.length; x++) {
    name = subscriberinfo[x].className;  // <-- Here is the change
    if (name == 'subscriberinfo') {
      subscriberinfo[x].style.display = 
          (subscriberinfo[x].id == thechosenone) ? 'block' : 'none';
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Your braces are out of alignment, and it is bugging me.

Comment: Do `subscriberinfo[x].className || subscriberinfo[x].getAttribute("class")` to use whichever property is available (i.e., use `className`, or fall back to `getAttribute("class")` if `className` is not available.

Comment: Do you know if there is some cases where `className` does not exists but `getAttribute("class")` exists? On this [site](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_html.html), `className` seems to work many more widely!